# Is it possible that there is a net torque on a body but still it is not rotating or angularly accelerating?

Tags: angular-momentum, torque, rotation

Is there any case possible in which we apply a torque on a body, but that torque does not make the body turn but instead change it's angular momentum or vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose an axis that does not coincide with the center of mass, then a net torque may change the angular momentum about that axis, but not be associated with an object rotating about its center.

Imagine a block and we pick an axis that is completely outside that block.  If we release the block, the gravitational force on it does not act through our axis and therefore a net torque exists.  If we calculate the angular momentum of the block with respect to that axis, it is changing during freefall.

If the axis contains the center of mass, then a net torque will be associated with change in rotational velocity.

Comment: and can you please give an example of the case when the angular momentum of the body would be zero but there is angular acceleration?

Comment: If there is net torque, angular momentum around that axis cannot remain zero.  You can imagine a case where there is zero net torque and angular momentum stays zero, but where rotation speed changes.

Comment: In case of a torque can the ''change'' in angular momentum be zero? Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible for a system to experience net torque but have no angular acceleration. This can happen when the system is not rigid or if the mass of the system varies with time. The angular momentum of the system WILL certainly change due to the net torque, but it is not necessary that the only way angular momentum changes is through a change in angular velocity.